# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error in java

Tags: java

So basically, I've created a contains method and it prints out the correct output I need but after it does this it gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at MethodTesting.main(MethodTesting.java:90)
```

Not sure why when it displays the output no worries? If anyone can give me an idea of what i'm doing wrong?? My code is below, i've tried adjusting the length to just length and length-1 as seen below. I've written the code in strings as opposed to char arrays however it wouldn't give me the right result. Hoping someone can shed some light perhaps?

```
        //contains method
    char[] st = "Hello World".toCharArray();
    char[] substr = "llo".toCharArray();
    for(int contains=0; contains<st.length-1; contains++){
        if(substr[contains] == st[contains]){
            for(int j=contains; j<st.length-1; j++){
                if(st[j] == substr[j]){
                }
                else{
                    contains = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("CONTAINS");
        System.out.println(contains);
    }
```

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `if(substr[contains] == st[contains])` this line is causing the problem. In your example `substr` has size 2, but `contains` index can be as large as 10.

Comment: looks like by setting contains=-1, the line if(substr[contains] == st[contains]) will fail, as it will try to refer to substr[-1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to search a substring of a string, this can be done in `String.contains()` method. If you are trying to implement the method yourself, then you have to change your code like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    char[] st = "Hello World".toCharArray();
    char[] substr = "llo".toCharArray();

    for(int contains = 0; contains < st.length - substr.length; contains++) {
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j < substr.length; j++) {
            if(st[contains + j] != substr[j]) {    // mismatch    
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == substr.length)   // Every character in substr has been matched
           System.out.println("Contains");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it's not longer giving me the error but the changes you suggested @RafiKamal now creates an infinite loop that doesn't print. Also shouldn't the second if statement be placed elsewhere as it doesn't seem to pick up the variable j at that position?

Comment: @EvangelineSlape I've pasted the full code with small modification.

Comment: Thanks so much @RafiKamal that worked a treat! Been racking my brains all day trying to get it to work!!

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays aren't of equal length, yet in your second loop, you make an assumption that they are.  `contains` can be a value higher than `substr.length`, and consequently, `j` will be, too.

To ensure that you don't step off the array while iterating, fix your bounds in your second loop.

Change `for(int j=contains; j<st.length-1; j++)` to `for(int j=contains; j<substr.length; j++)`.  This will ensure that your second loop is never executed if `contains > substr.length`, whereas it was executing as long as `j < st.length()-1`.

Comment: Thanks, @Makoto the only issue is now it prints in sequence of 0,1,2 as if it's printing each time the contains variable is being incremented.

Answer (score 0):

`st` array length and `substr` lengths are different.So the line 
`j<st.length-1;` should be `j<substr.length-1;`